# Finite lattice dimension and planarity

Tags: lattice-orders

I have been struggling for several days on this question, now it is time for you folks to enlighten me :)

In the book *Lattice Theory: Foundations* from George Gratzer ([pdf file](http://www.xituju.com/download/file/20170704/20170704153281618161.pdf)), it is stated, page 9, the following :

> Define the order-dimension, dim(P), of an order P as the smallest cardinal m such that P is a suborder of a product of m chains. For a finite lattice L,
>   planarity is equivalent to dim(L) ≤ 2

From what I understand : if I take any planar Hasse diagram, I should be able to represent it as a subdiagram of a diagram representing the product of at most 2 chains.

Let us consider the following planar diagram :

[planar Hasse diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIcF2.png)

It is clearly not a subdiagram of a Hasse diagram representing one chain... So it should be a subdiagram of a Hasse diagram representing the product of two chains (as it is a planar diagram).

A product of two chains basically looks like that (here, it represents the product of a chain of 4 elements over a chain of 3 elements) :

[Product of two chains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLMfl.png)

Which brings me to my question : I do not picture any diagram that would represent a product of two chains, and whose any subdiagram would look like the planar one I introduced first. For example, in a diagram representing a product of two chains, there is no such a vertex gathering 4 edges going down as it is the case for the top vertex in the former planar diagram. This is in contradiction with the Gratzer statement I copied at the beginning of this post.

If anybody can explain where I am wrong, I would really be thankful !

Comment: For a finite **lattice** $L$, planarity is equivalent to dim $L \leq 2$. Not every poset  is a lattice; the poset in your linked picture is not a lattice.

Comment: Yes, your poset has no least element.

Comment: Oh what a dummy !.. I plead not guilty as George Grätzer decided to mention lattices before defining it... I mixed Posets and lattices. Many thanks !